# Woocomerce where it stores the orders and subscriptions in Database?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

Im doing a payment gateway for Colombia, i need some help in the database, any of you know what table or where is stored the orders and the subscriptions in the worpress database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all orders are in **wp_posts** table
and
subscriptions in **shop_subscription** custom post type

but its recommended to ALWAYS backup whole database